# Tomcat when we get an exceptions in background, error page to be displayed with specific error

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, vaadin7

Is there any solution to navigate to an error page when we encounter any exception in apache 7.0 server?

We are using **Apache 7.0 server with servlet 3.0.**

So how to configure the exceptions in web.xml ie, which will enable it to navigate to error page when we face exceptions in server ?

Instead of configuring in web.xml, is there any other possible way to achieve this ?

Comment: for configuring web.xml, see http://blog.codeleak.pl/2013/04/how-to-custom-error-pages-in-tomcat.html

Answer (score 0):

Use try{} catch{} and in the catch use Redirect() or RequestDispatcher function to get to a new page that should be already created by you...
and to send the message....u can use setAttribute() and getAttribute() to show the error on the new page.

Comment: It is not possible to add the try/catch mechanism in all classes right.So could please provide me the solution related to web.xml configuration so that the exception handling can be done through this and code will be reduced.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the error to be handle in web.xml file. When any error occurs it will be redirected to that page automatically. This is clear solution.

```html
<error-page>
  <error-code>400</error-code>
  <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/errorpages/ErrorPage400.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
  <error-code>401</error-code>
  <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/errorpages/ErrorPage401.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
  <error-code>403</error-code>
  <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/errorpages/ErrorPage403.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/errorpages/ErrorPage404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
  <error-code>500</error-code>
  <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/errorpages/ErrorPage500.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

[More about this on this link](http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/error-pages-and-error-handling/1.-handling-error-codes-and-exceptions-by-the-web.xml.html)

Comment: Hi, We are not using the Vaadin Technology(UI FrameWork) not the JSP. So please provide me the another solution because i have tried with the above solution already.

Comment: I am confused with your comment, Can you please come again.  "We are not using the Vaadin Technology(UI FrameWork) not the JSP."

Comment: Hey Sorry, We are using the Vaadin Technology(UI FrameWork) not the JSP.I have tried with this configuration.. <error-page><exception-type>java.lang.NullPointerException</exception-type>
<location>/myui</location></error-page>.In logic by using spring (@ExceptionHandler) i am trying to displying the sout("Testing");.But this is also not working. So Could you please suggest me.